# How to fix hdajackretask error tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig

Tags: drivers, pulseaudio, alsa

I tried using `hdajackretask` to make my mic jack act as another headphone jack, but when I hit apply it would say

```
tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig
```

and then wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by making the changes (Microphone→Headphones, Channel 3→1) and then setting it as a boot setting. There was no error on boot and it totally worked.

I guess some other service was using the resource or something.

Comment: can you explain more about the solution? thanks

Comment: 7 years later? nope, I have no idea. best of luck, feel free to add a comment/answer here if you figure things out!